# Oracle Extract Value from CDATA

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with column

```
DETAIL         VARCHAR2(4000)
```

One of the sample data that is being stored in DETAIL column is

```
<![CDATA[<DIV STYLE="text-align:LEFT;"><SPAN STYLE="letter-spacing:0px;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:'Verdana';">Value to be extract</SPAN></DIV>]]>
```

Is there a way to extract the text in a SQL select query?

Comment: Is it always that format?

Comment: The styling html will be stored within the <![CDATA[  ]]>. Depending of the style defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regexp_substr(detail, '>([^<]+)<', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/651d0/4) - thanks to sgeddes

Comment: Thank you :) it handles dynamic value well

Comment: do you know where i can find the explanation for your reg expression?

Comment: @jjpan - [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions148.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)

Comment: Egor must be from alien planet as he speaks fluently in >([^<]+)<... Congrats!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: can i set the occurrence to 'ANY', instead of hardcoding the number of occurrence?

Comment: got it. i used regexp_count:)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it -- although the format would need to stay as above:

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DETAIL,'<![CDATA[',''),']]>','')).EXTRACT('/DIV/SPAN/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() 
FROM yourtable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/651d0/1)

Basically this converts the detail column into html (removes cdata info) and then uses `getstringval` to return the value between certain tags.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb04cre.htm#i1024803

Answer (score 3):

Proper way to do such things through Oracle XML DB features:

```
select 
  value_test
from 
XMLTable('$p'    
  passing XMLParse(content '<![CDATA[<DIV STYLE="text-align:LEFT;"><SPAN STYLE="letter-spacing:0px;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:''Verdana'';">Value to be extract</SPAN></DIV>]]>')
  as "p"
  columns value_test varchar2(4000) path '/text()'
);
```

Another variant to do so:

```
select
  dbms_xmlgen.convert(
    XMLQuery('data($p)'    
      passing by value XMLParse(content '<![CDATA[<DIV STYLE="text-align:LEFT;"><SPAN STYLE="letter-spacing:0px;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:''Verdana'';">Value to be extract</SPAN></DIV>]]>')
      as "p"          
      returning content
    ).getCLOBVal(), 
    1
  )  
from dual;
```